# Can you make pastel color palette in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm getting a big job done in Processing and thter's a pallete of pastel colors I'm got from another stackovfw quetion, it's like this.
Except I don't know how to adapt it to processing!

```java
public Color generateRandomColor(Color mix) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int red = random.nextInt(256);
    int green = random.nextInt(256);
    int blue = random.nextInt(256);

    // mix the color
    if (mix != null) {
        red = (red + mix.getRed()) / 2;
        green = (green + mix.getGreen()) / 2;
        blue = (blue + mix.getBlue()) / 2;
    }

    Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
    return color;
}
```

Maybe if I did this?

```java
    void color() {
 float red = (random(256));
 float green = (random(256));
 float blue = (random(256));
}
if (mix != null){
red = (red + mix.getREd())/2;
green = (green + mix.getGreen())/2;
blue = (blue + mixgetBlue())/2;
}
color (red,gree,blue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use code you find on the internet, it's really important that you understand what it's doing. It looks to me like the function in your first code snippet is averaging a random color with the parameter color. Whether that produces a pastel color depends on the parameter color, but I suppose if you passed in pure white then it would be like mixing a random color with white?

Anyway, I recommend you take a step back and think about exactly what you mean by pastel color. Is it just a lighter color? If so there are easier ways to generate that. For example instead of creating a completely random color, you could create a random color whose components are on the lighter side.

Here's an example:

```
void draw(){
 frameRate(2);

 float r = random(128, 256);
 float g = random(128, 256);
 float b = random(128, 256);

 background(r, g, b); 
}
```

This code generates a random color whose red, green, and blue components are all between 128 and 256. This rules out darker colors whose components can be closer to 0.

Comment: @agaragaragar Happy to help. Were you socks pastel colored? :p